# Hide a div on file upload button click

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I need a functionality that

where a image is shown in default

when a file uploaded using `{input type="file"}` that image as to be hidden

http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1/

```
<div id='browse-img-sh'><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Pretty_office_icon_part_2/64/man.png" /></div>    
<input name="" type="file">
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I did its just a toggle http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vVsAn/3955/

Comment: Hi! Tushar Thanks for your fast replay...

There is a problem if we upload more than on time

For the first time its working perfectly but after that if files re uploaded the div again showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        

        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
        {
            if (jQuery('#file_input')[0].files[0] != undefined) {
                jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("File API is not supported");
        }
    });
});
```

I think this can help you.